# Skylnmobi : Virus? Backdoor ? What is it?

Tags: processes

OS : Android 4.4.2

This process like thing (Skylnmobi) opens in background whenever any app is opened.

Even if I kill the process through app manager it still runs in background.

It also uses data when connected to internet (known by analysing data usage of the device)
I have tried many antivirus softwares but they have not detected any unusual behaviour related to this process.

I am not getting straight results through googling, so does any one know about it?

Comment: What phone do you have? Did you get it from the manufacturer, or through your carrier?

Comment: It is a tablet device provided by our college, actually this problem surfaced only a few days back., and none of my friends, who have the same device have this issue.

Comment: Can you or have you done a factory reset?

Comment: You wouldn't get straight results from Google because you're using a localized issue as a search query. Try searching for advanced ways on finding and removing a malware from an Android device. The first thing you need to know is the package name of the malware (assuming that it's an app), then find out whether that is a user app or system app. Report us your results by [edit]ing your question.